# What screen aspects are HD and Full HD?

Tags: android, screen, aspect-ratio

What screen aspects are HD and Full HD: long or not long? How/what do you calculate? What about tablets? I've seen [screen aspect](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) and [the list](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-2.0.html#dev-features). But they don't say about large and xlarge screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

small, normal, large and xlarge are screen **SIZE**

small: QVGA (320×240)

normal: HVGA (480×320)

large: VGA (640×480)

xlarge: larger than HVGA(720x960)

ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi are screen **density** (number of pixles in inch).

LDPI: Low density, ~120 dots per inch

MDPI: Medium density, ~160 dots per inch

HDPI: High density, ~240 dots per inch

XHDPI: eXtra High density, ~320 dots per inch

XXHDPI: eXtra eXtra High density, ~480 dots per inch

XXXHDPI: eXtra eXtra eXtra High density, ~640 dots per inch

For example, you may have a `large` screen with `mdpi` resolution.

Handsets are often small or normal
7" and 10" tablets are large.

Read more:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphics_display_resolution
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mobile_phones_with_HD_display

Comment: you've wrote HVGA for both normal and xlarge. What about WQVGA, WVGA, FWVGA??? What sizes are they? What is 720x1280(galaxy s3)? or 1080x1920(galaxy s4) or 2560 x 1600(10'' tablet):HVGA, WVGA or something else?

Comment: thank you for your answer. sorry i didn't see the second link you gave about display resolution. Although it doesn't mention WQVGA and FWVGA. Otherwise it answers my question.